# Divisors of every integer in a set

Tags: divisibility, gcd-and-lcm

Let $S$ be the set of all positive integers $n$ s.t. $n^2$ is a multiple of both $24$ and $108$. Which of the following integers are divisors of every integer $n$ in $S$?

**Attempt:**

---

$n^2=24k  \wedge n^2=108j; k,j \in \mathbb{Z} $

$n^2=3*2^3k \wedge n^2=3^2*2^2j$

$n=2*\sqrt{6k} \wedge n=6j$

I don't know where to go from here.

---

The answer choices are

- A:12
- B:24
- C:36
- D:72

Comment: If a number is multiple of 24 and 108 it is a multiple of their lcm.

Comment: How does one find the lcm? It's easy to check, but how does one do it quickly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$n^2=3*2^3k \wedge n^2=3^3*2^2j$

For $n^2$ to be a multiple of both $3*2^3$ and $3^3*2^2$, it has to be a multiple of $3^3*2^3$(Just take the highest prime powers).  The minimum $n$ for this to happen is $n=3^2*2^2$. Every integer in $S$ is a multiple of $3^2*2^2$.

Comment: I disagree about taking the highest prime powers. Shouldn't we take the prime powers found in both? Why are we taking prime powers? Doesn't $n^2$ have to be a multiple of $3*2^3$ rather than $3^3 * 2^3$? @ganeshie8 I'm thinking about common factors for $n^2$

Comment: @Germania as you want let $n^2 = 3*2^3$. Is it a multiple of both $24$ and $108$ ?

Comment: Oh, you're right. $3*2^3$ isn't a multiple of 108. It's only multiple of 24.

Comment: Np:) Here $3^3*2^3$ is the lcm of $3*2^3$ and $3^3*2^2$. We found lcm by taking the highest prime powers... Had we taken the lowest prime powers, we would have gotten the gcd.